# Is it possible to activate the flash while filming on some devices?

Tags: camera, photos

I would like to know if it is possible to turn on the flash while filming on some devices?

Comment: AFAIK, this doesn't depend on the devices, but on the app itself. Do you have any issues with your device (if that's the case, which model, Android version, and the name of the app?)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.